# Data Being Excluded When Using $unwind in MongoDB View

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB backend I have defined a Mongo view which returns a list of employees. A problem I'm running into is, if I use a `$lookup` followed by an  `$unwind` in one of my aggregation stages, and that particular person doesn't yet have any data for that property, then they will be excluded from the returned data. I'm talking about aggregation like this:

```
{
    $lookup: { "from" : "departments", "localField" : "department", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "department" }
},

{
  $unwind: { "path" : "$department" }
},
```

Is there a way around this: where I can use a `$lookup` and `$unwind` here, while also NOT excluding that person if they don't happen to have any data for that field? And would that be accomplished here, or in the `$project` stage I call a couple of stages later (see code below)?

```
{
    $project: { "name" : 1.0, "department" : { "name" : "$department.name" }, "branch" : { "name" : "$branch.name" }, "addresses" : 1.0, "notes" : 1.0, "phones" : 1.0, "emails" : 1.0, "updatedAt" : 1.0 }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) of `$unwind` to achieve this:

```
{
  $lookup: { 
     "from" : "departments", 
     "localField" : "department", 
     "foreignField" : "_id", 
     "as" : "department" }
 },
 {
   $unwind: { 
     "path" : "$department",
     "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of MongoDB

```
  If you specify a path for a field that does not exist in an input document or the field 
is an empty array, $unwind, by default, ignores the input document
 and will not output documents for that input document.

   New in version 3.2: To output documents where the array field is missing, 
null or an empty array, use the option preserveNullAndEmptyArrays.
```

You can try executing following aggregate query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: { 
         "from" : "departments", 
         "localField" : "department", 
         "foreignField" : "_id", 
         "as" : "department" }
     },
     {
       $unwind: { 
         "path" : "$department",
         "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
    }])
```